# How can I count the sum of gaps between date ranges

Tags: sql-server

```
t_no.    eff_date         term_date
65803   2011-01-01        2011-06-30
65803   2011-09-01        2011-11-30
65804   2012-02-01        NULL
65805   2011-02-01        2011-06-30
```

I want sql code that calculate the gap between 2 different record with the same t_no. (e.g. 2 months for 65803).

Data could have one or more record for the same t_no.

Comment: Where are you getting 3 months?

Comment: @KDiTraglia the 3 month gap is between the eff_date and the term_date between the two records

Comment: will you only have a max of two entries for each record or can you have more than 2?  If you have more than two which range do you want to use? What RDBMS?  What have you tried?

Comment: i'm using sql server 2008. yes as i wrote above, could have one or multiple records.

Comment: @user1429225 can you have 3 records for the same key?  If so how do you do the calculation?

Comment: @user1429225: if you had three records: `Jan 1 to Jan 10`, `Jan 15 to Jan 25` and `Apr 1 to Apr 10`, what would the output be?

Comment: and i tried using cursor but it doesn't work

Comment: @user1429225: "it doesn't work" is very descriptive.

Comment: Is there another (primary key) column that you are not showing?

Comment: sum up all gaps between the dates 5+65

Comment: no primary key in the table, jst unique identifier , other dates stuff

Comment: i added the records to a temp table with auto increment primary key to make it more convenience

Answer (score 3):

```
WITH    q AS
        (
        SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t_no ORDER BY term_date) rn
        FROM    mytable
        )
SELECT  qp.t_no, SUM(DATEDIFF(day, qp.term_date, qn.eff_date))
FROM    q qp
JOIN    q qn
ON      qn.t_no = qp.t_no
        AND qn.rn = qp.rn + 1
GROUP BY
        qp.t_no
```

Comment: well i don't know what over means, but i'll study it and try this.